# Toolbar button image suppressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I have a viewcontroller with a toolbar with 2 bar button items. The image on one is a simple flat icon. The other is a complex image reduced to 28x28 pixels from a 256x256 image. The complex image shows up as a blob as shown below. The actual image is also show in the picture. It is not clear what I am doing wrong. The project code is available in the following link:
[Project code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tp5rxey1ocmtygf/AACQAv2WbMh_w-i1-TEwevJia?dl=0)

[image: viewController with toolbar]

Comment: Do you mean the second image in the right of your toolbar?

Comment: Yes. The image that shows up as a rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Griffith on Apple Developer Forum provided this explanation which made a lot of sense. I need to redesign my icons if I want to proceed along this line:

**Toolbar images are normally rendering mode "template" - only the alpha channel is used. Any non-transparent pixels are drawn in the bar's tint color. It may be possible to create a UIImage with rendering mode "always original" to preserve the look of your image, but then it won't respond to changes in tint color.**

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your project. The first thing you should do is to move your image files into the images.xcassets folder. [Read here to understand why.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1)

The image you are trying to display is actually just a red rectangle:
[image]

As you can see, opening in another program also just displays it as a red rectangle. Be sure to use the correct Image file. The problem lies not with your project but rather the image file you are using.

Comment: Spelling mistake is unlikely. I used only Interface Builder to select the file from a list of files that I have added to the project. I did not type anything. I will check the storyboard in xml to see if there is an error.

Comment: There is something in rendering the file in a 28x28 space that is the issue. I display the same file in the UIImage and it shows up as seen in the screenshot

Comment: **BarButton** Images should be approx 44x44 and more according to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

Comment: I changed the image to 44x44 and still does not help. I will see if I can find an image from an apple sample. I am doing something fundamentally wrong. I hope someone can review my code in the link I provided and help understand the issue.